# Increment forEachFeatureAtPixel OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, markers

I draw some markers in my Map. Those markers, have a User Icon (It is a image in png) I would like, that, when I use forEachFeatureAtPixel, I can click in all area of this user Icon.

So, my question is, How can I increment the area to "forEachFeatureAtPixel"?

It is my function:

```
// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
  function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
 if (feature) {

  //..................
 } 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly but...

You shouldn't have to increment anything in your code..

Try this:

```
// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var features = [];
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    features.push(feature);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    console.dir(features[i]); //Displays object in browser console log
  }
});
```

Comment: I edit my question, I think that is more understandly.